# Implement jTable grid using sql database without repository

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, jquery-jtable

I am trying to implement jtable with my asp.net web application using c# and after downloading the demo I am able to get it to work with a repository like they did. My problem is now I need the grid to use those same CRUD behaviors but with a SQL database.

I have been going through every article I could find on google trying to find the right way to go about this. Now I think using Linq to SQL is the correct way to bind my database to my grid but when I try to implement it its totally wrong. I was looking into NHibernate but I am totally at a loss.

I was thinking I need to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomer(int id) 
{
    using (var db = new SampleSQLDatabase())
    {
        return Json(db.GetData(id).sample1());
    }
```

}

But not really sure if this is the route I need to go. I'm really leaning towards nHibernate but need some direction at the best way to get this done.

Comment: first map the dataclasses to the database using FluentNHibernate or NHibernate MappingByCode then

    `using(var session = sessionfactory.OpenSession())
    {
        return Json(session.Get<Entity>(id));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple, probably easier than you realize.

In your controller you need a way to retrieve the database results and then get the result as Json. This is an example out of one of my own projects.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();
    public JsonResult GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var customerRecord = db.CustomerList.Find(id);
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = customerRecord }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

And the DataContext class is quite straight forward, it extends DbContext. Example as follows:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RMA> RmaRecordList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> AddressList { get; set; }
    }
```